# Java: unable to delete dynamodb item value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete a field called "dog" from all of the items that resides on table animals, or that I use the following code:

```
    Table table= dynamoDB.getTable("animals");
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName("animals");
    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);


    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){

        table.updateItem(new PrimaryKey("<Primary partition key name>", item.get("<Primary partition key name>"),"<Primary sort key name>", item.get("<Primary sort key name>")), 
new AttributeUpdate("dog").delete());

    }
```

But I am getting:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: value type: class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
.
.
.
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: value type: class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
```

What am I doing wrong here?

by the way, I also tried:

```
   UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                    .withPrimaryKey("<Primary partition key name>", item.get("<Primary partition key name>"),"<Primary sort key name>", item.get("<Primary sort key name>"))
                    .withUpdateExpression("REMOVE dog");
            table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

But got the same exception. (Also tried DELETE instead of REMOVE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the issue, I cant believe I missed it....
Remember kids, its mandatory to look at the actual values when debugging!

So instead of using just:

```
item.get("<property name>")
```

You need to explicitly ask for a String like so:

```
item.get("<property name>").getS()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old V1 DynamoDB API, which is not best practice. It better practice to use the Amazon DynamoDB V2 Java API.

**The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**

If you are not familiar with the AWS SDK for Java V2, see:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

For this use case (which is modifying an item), the solution is to use the Enhanced Client, which lets you map Java objects to a table. For more information, see:

[Mapping items in DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html)s

Using the Enhanced Clint, you can modify an item with code like this:

```
    package com.example.dynamodb;


import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSortKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import java.time.Instant;


/*
 * Prior to running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with these columns:
 *   - id - the id of the record that is the key
 *   - custName - the customer name
 *   - email - the email value
 *   - registrationDate - an instant value when the item was added to the table
 *  Also, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class EnhancedModifyItem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String usage = "Usage:\n" +
                "    UpdateItem <key> <email> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    key - the name of the key in the table (id120).\n" +
                "    email - the value of the modified email column.\n" ;

       if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
       }

        String key = args[0];
        String email = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
                .build();

        String updatedValue = modifyItem(enhancedClient,key,email);
        System.out.println("The updated name value is "+updatedValue);
        ddb.close();
    }


    public static String modifyItem(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient, String keyVal, String email) {
        try {
            //Create a DynamoDbTable object
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));

            //Create a KEY object
            Key key = Key.builder()
                    .partitionValue(keyVal)
                    .build();

            // Get the item by using the key and update the email value.
            Customer customerRec = mappedTable.getItem(r->r.key(key));
            customerRec.setEmail(email);
            mappedTable.updateItem(customerRec);
            return customerRec.getEmail();

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

You can find this V2 example and others for Amazon DYnamoDB here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer! I am actually using dynamodbv2, ie: "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB". Note that my question is how to delete a value within an item but not the item itself.

Comment: dynamodbv2 is still V1. Note that any package starting with com.amazonaws.services... is v1. V2 packages are  software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb...

Comment: Oh I missed that! thanks. Now I just need to find out how to delete a property value within an item.

Comment: Have you tried to update that item without the specific column value.

Comment: See this code - using the Enhanced Client for the DynamoDB API to modify an item.

Comment: Thanks its working. However, I found the solution to the issue I originally had with version 1.